# Debugging the Azure Stream Analytics Project in visual studio

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I developed the UDF javascript function and I called it in the query window,I kept the breakpoint in the javascript function and I was not able to hit the break point. Can some one help with ,how to hit the break point for UDF function.

Answer (score 1):

We do not support UDF debugging now for VS tools. Currently we are working on .NET UDF support and breakpoint debugging will be fully supported. we are planning to release .NET based UDF October

Comment: ok.is there any thing like console.log so that I can put the trace log and do the debugging.I did tried console.log but it was throwing error.